# Is it a good approach to prove that the closed ball $B[a, r]=\{x\in X :d(x, a) \le r\}$ is a closed set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

$(X, d) $ be any metric space.

$a\in X$ and $r>0$, then the closed ball $B[a, r]=\{x\in X :d(x, a) \le r\}$
is closed set.

My Attempt:

I want to show $B[a, r]$ contains all of it's cluster points.

Let, $ x\in X$ be a cluster point of $B[a, r]$.

To show, $x\in B[a, r]$.

Since, $x\in X$ is a cluster point of $B[a, r]$,

$\exists  (x_n) \subset B[a, r]\setminus \{x\}$ such that $(x_n) \to x$ in $(X, d) $.

Then, $d(x_n, a) \le r$  ....... (I)

And, $d(x_n, x) \to 0 $ as  $ n \to {\infty}$..... (II)

Now, $d(a, x) \le d(a, x_n) +d(x_n, x) $
$\implies$ $d(a, x) \le r +d(x_n, x) $

Taking, $n\to {\infty}$ , $d(x, a) \le r$

Hence, $x\in B[a, r]$ .

Thus, $B[a, r]$ is closed in $(X, d) $.

I think my proof is okay. But, I want to know if there is any mistakes. Please verify my proof.Thanks

Comment: The simplest is if you know $f:X\to\mathbb R^{\geq0}$ defined as $f(x)=d(x,a)$ is continuous. Then $B[a,r]=f^{-1}([0,r]),$ and $[0,r]$ is closed in $\mathbb R^{\geq0}.$

Comment: Your proof looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

Your proof is really hiding three separate results:

1. $[0,r]$ is closed in $[0,\infty),$ under the usual metric,
2. $x\mapsto d(x,a)$ is continuous, and
3. If $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous function with metric spaces $X$ and $Y,$ and $C\subseteq Y$ is closed, then $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed.

But it is useful to know each of the separate results $1,2,3.$

$1.$ says that if $x_i$ is a convergent sequence in $[0,\infty)$ with all $x_i\in[0,a]$ then the limit is in $[0,a].$

$2.$ follows because:
$$\left|d(x,a)-d(y,a)\right|\leq d(x,y).$$

$3.$ is only a little harder. If $x_i\in f^{-1}(C),$ and converges to $x\in X,$ then by continuity, $\lim_{i\to\infty}f(x_i)=f(x).$ But all $f(x_i)\in C$ and $C$ closed means $f(x)\in C,$ and hence $x\in f^{-1}(C).$

Comment: Thank you sir. It's really helpful.